# Releasing Camera takes a long time after locked screen

Tags: android, flash, camera

In my flashlight widget, [there is a service](https://github.com/rahatarmanahmed/simple-led-widget/blob/master/src/com/freek/ledwidget/LEDService.java) that manages the camera and turns it on or off. If you turn on the LED and lock the screen for a while, it takes a long time to turn off when you  unlock your phone(~40 seconds!). I checked and it turns out that it's because the camera takes forever to release itself. What is causing this, and how can I fix it?

Comment: It is probably because something wrong with your code, please post some of it so we can help you.

Comment: There is a link to the source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem. But if you keep the device on with a wakelock (this will keep the cpu on, see http://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/wakelock.html) the problem does not occure. Just make sure, that you release the lock when you release the cam.

Hope that helps